# Get live Exchange rates with coinbase api

Tags: coinbase-api

I want to get live lists of all the exchange rates with Coinbase API.  I realize that by using this: https://coinbase.com/api/v1/currencies/exchange_rates, I always get the same values, I guess these values change once per day. Is it possible to get live rates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get nearly realtime data is to use one of the official or unofficial APIs. There exists a function you can use to receive the real time data you want. [Coinbase API Reference](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?javascript#get-exchange-rates)

**Edit 1:** As an alternative, you can use the following links for receiving the [Buy](https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy) and [Sell](https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/sell) prices.

I don't know if this public API is as reliable as an authenticated access.

**Edit 2:** Even better: The [spot price](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?javascript#get-spot-price) API Endpoint.